# Bulk insert into MS SQL Creating ObjectID's

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am running an ETL from a spatial view into publication database. The view has results in duplicate ObjectID's. I started working with the get_ids SP example from ESRI, but that seems to be built more for a single record insert and not a bulk insert. Here is my example...

```
DECLARE @id as integer
DECLARE @num_ids as integer
EXEC L.i16_get_ids 2, 1, @id output, @num_ids output; 

INSERT INTO L.TAXPARCELWCONDOS ([OBJECTID]
           ,[PARCELNO]
           ,[SHAPE])
SELECT @id
      ,[PARCELNO] ,[shape]
  FROM [Parcel].[L].[view_TaxParcelwCondos];
END
```

How can I generate new ObjectID's for the insert.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Create a temp table with an identity column for Object ID.
Insert the View there and then move that into the publication table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE #TAXPARCELWCONDOS(
 [OBJECTID] int identity(1,1) not null,
 [PARCELNO] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
 [SHAPE] [geometry] NULL)


 
INSERT INTO #TAXPARCELWCONDOS ([PARCELNO]
           ,[SHAPE])
SELECT [PARCELNO] ,[shape]
  FROM [Parcel].[L].[view_TaxParcelwCondos];



TRUNCATE TABLE L.TAXPARCELWCONDOS;

INSERT INTO L.TAXPARCELWCONDOS ([OBJECTID],[PARCELNO]
           ,[SHAPE])
SELECT [OBJECTID],[PARCELNO] ,[shape]
  FROM #TAXPARCELWCONDOS;
  
DROP TABLE #TAXPARCELWCONDOS